# Unable to perform memory profiling on Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xcode-instruments

I have tried used the following tools to perform memory profiling on my Xamarin app.

1. MonoTouch-Profiler    - Works, but only on the simulator.
2. Xamarin Profiler - Can't take snapshots. Also, app does not record initially and crashes on trying to record again.
3. Xcode Instruments -  Can't record anything using Allocations and Leaks.

I'm using an iPad with iOS 8.1.3 running on it. I'm using Xamarin(5.7.1) and Xcode(6.1.1). SGen is the GC and Debugging and Profiling has been enabled.

I can't figure if I am missing something. Any help is appreciated!